# Error message "is ambiguous for the type Other" when calling an overloaded method

Tags: java

I know the following program will have a compile error as:

> The method runThis(Integer) is ambiguous for the type Other

What I don't understand is the reason.

```
public class Other {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        runThis(null);

    }

    private static void runThis(Integer integer){
        System.out.println("Integer");
    }

    private static void runThis(Object object){
        System.out.println("Object");
    }

    private static void runThis(ArithmeticException ae){
        System.out.println("ArithmeticException");
    }

}
```

Also, when I change the program as follows it prints "ArithmeticException". Also I don't know the reason. Can anyone explain this to me?

```
public class Other {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    runThis(null);

}

private static void runThis(Exception exception){
    System.out.println("Exception");
}

private static void runThis(Object object){
    System.out.println("Object");
}

private static void runThis(ArithmeticException ae){
    System.out.println("ArithmeticException");
}
```

Comment: you want to declare the type(Exception /Integer) before call the runThis method

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you pass in `null`, that can be converted to any reference type.  Java will attempt to find the overloaded method with the most specific type.

In your first example, the possibilities are `Object`, `Integer`, and `ArithmeticException`.  `Integer` and `ArithmeticException` are both more specific than `Object`, yet neither are more specific than the other, so it's ambiguous.

In your second example, the possibilities are `Object`, `Exception`, and `ArithmeticException`.  `Exception` and `ArithmeticException` are both more specific than `Object`, but `ArithmeticException` is also more specific than `Exception`, so the ambiguity is resolved in favor of `ArithmeticException`.

Comment: As stated in [JLS 15.12.2.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5).

Comment: Hmm...that's something new to me.

Answer (score 5):

The `null` could be any `Object` (including an `Integer`). Add a cast,

Change this

```
runThis(null);
```

to

```
runThis((Integer) null);
```

or

```
runThis((Object) null);
```

And eliminate the ambiguity.